# Zoom SDK error (Already has other meetings in progress.)

Tags: php, wordpress, zoom-sdk

I got this error (Already has other meetings in progress) while joining the meeting in the zoom sdk.

I tried to check this error on zoom sdk forums but didn't found anything related to that.
[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9TTx.png)

Comment: https://devforum.zoom.us/t/web-sdk-showing-already-has-other-meetings-in-progress-error/32773

Comment: Is it possible to change the host while creating the meeting? @Anant-Alivetodie

Comment: Don't have any idea. Maybe the use of a VPN with different country selections can do it (while zoning classes via browser)? But I am not sure though.